# Arabic nvarchar column in mssql returned as ? in php using sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, apache, utf-8, sqlsrv

I have browsed every single utf-8 encoding question but I can't find an answer to mine. Basically I have an mssql database stored locally on my pc and I am using sqlsrv to connect to it. A column in my table called "ProductName" that is an nvarchar data type has arabic text in it, on my php statement instead of getting the arabic text echoed in an array I get question marks, now as everyone on all questions suggested I tried adding `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"` in my connection and now instead of getting question marks I get utf-8 characters like `\u0635\u0646\u0641 \u062e\u0627\u0645` now if I try to decode those? yes I get question marks again, sometimes I even get chineese symbols but never the arabic text. I tried decoding this in an online utf-8 decoder and I successfully get the arabic text, what seems to be the problem?

My php code:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"VarrOne_DataBAse","TrustServerCertificate"=>true, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    // echo "Connection established.<br />";
$sql = "SELECT ProductName
        FROM ItemData";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $results = Array($row['ProductName']);
    
      echo json_encode($results);

}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

I also tried using `iconv` for the conversion with no luck.
thank you!

**Edit**: I also tried setting the default charset in both apache and php to utf-8

Comment: Those unicode escapes you've given decode to "صنف خام" which looks, like arabic to me. Whatever you're using to _view_ the data is not correctly configured for UTF-8. https://3v4l.org/cMvd4

Comment: @Sammitch do you mean the hosting server I am using could be the problem?

Comment: No. The thing that is literally rendering the text on your screen. The browser, the terminal, etc.

Comment: The text that is stored in your database, what is it encoded as? Try checking with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php As a caution, `mb_detect_encoding` will interpret Windows-1252 as ISO-8859-1